# Show function $F: [0,1] \rightarrow \int_x^{x^3}f(t)dt$ is differentiable given continous function f

Tags: integration, derivatives

I have the function $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is continous and then
$F: [0,1] \rightarrow \int_x^{x^3}f(t)dt$.

I have to show that $F$ is differentiable and to calculate $F'$.

I know that because $f$ is continuous, it has an antiderivative of the form $\int_\alpha^xf(t)dt$ with $\alpha \in [0,1] $. Can I split $\int_x^{x^3}f(t)dt$ into integrals of the previous form and use substitution for one of them?

Is there any theorem I missing or perhaps an obvious trick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define $G(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$, then $G$ is differentiable on $(0,1)$. Note that $F(x)=G(x^3)-G(x)$. Differentiability of $F$ follows from differentiability of $G$ and chain rule.